# Convert acceleration with gravity to pure acceleration?

Tags: javascript, html, accelerometer

By using `event.accelerationIncludingGravity` on Android, it returns a value of

```
x: -0.2
y: +0.1
z: +9.1
```

when resting on a flat surface. However, I want to get acceleration without gravity but `event.acceleration` is not supported. Is there a way to convert it by Math? In [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/#toc-dm4) there is an example removing the gravity factor, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  // Convert the value from acceleration to degrees acceleration. x|y is the 
  // acceleration according to gravity, we'll assume we're on Earth and divide 
  // by 9.81 (earth gravity) to get a percentage value, and then multiply that 
  // by 90 to convert to degrees.                                
  var tiltLR = Math.round(((acceleration.x) / 9.81) * -90);
  var tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.y + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);
```

---

[Example script graphing acceleration values](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NNk2z/show) (not from HTML5Rocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. You got numbers for the x and y axis that are essentially 0, keep taking the measurement of the device resting on a flat surface and average all of your x and y values respectively and you will get your degree of error in each direction. The acceleration is measured in m/s^2. (meters per second squared). The gravitational acceleration at the earth's surface is 9.86m/s^2. In an ideal physics problem all you would have to do is subtract this number and you would get your answer. If you were trying to calculate speed then this would be a more complex problem, but the earth's gravitational acceleration does not accelerate. You do have a larger degree of error in the z-axis, but not if you calculate the degree of error as a percentage of the actual value. Or you are about 300km above sea level.

Comment: I just tested that `9.86 - e.acceleration.z` works fine when the device is facing up. But as soon as I tilt it, the gravity factor starts to influence other axis as well. [This script](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) I think is helpful because it takes gravity in account, but I don't know really know how to use it. (and it is written in Java)

Comment: Yeah the native functionality for the hardware seems to be outperform mobile development for the time being.